# What is the difference between a dialog based and frame based application in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I'm trying to learn GUI-programming with C++ using Codeblocks 16.01, wxWidgets 3.1.0 and MinGW and when I start up the wxWidget wizard in Codeblocks I get to choose whether my application type is dialog based or frame based.

[image]

**My question is: What does dialog and frame based application mean? What is the difference?**

Comment: You can use the dialog resource editor to fill the content of a window, roughly a point-and-click UI designer but with 1990s sensibilities.  Not so sure CodeBlocks has such an editor, look at DialogBlocks or ResEdit.  In a frame-based app you have to write code to create the widgets that fill the window.

Comment: Thank you for your help @HansPassant so shortly put: In a dialog based application you can use mouse to click-and-drag to make your application with the coding automated and in a frame based application you have to do the coding of the application yourself. Did I get it? :)

Comment: @jjepsuomi, that's not necessary true. The dialog based application is exactly what it is - you have a dialog as you main window with the "OK" and "Cancel" button. You fill out some data and hit "OK" and you are done. With the Frame-based approach, you have a main window and then you put some GUI elements - menu, toolbar, statusbar and then you do some processing when you select the menu/click toolbar button/press some hot key. However, with wxWidgets both approaches can be done with drag-and-drop/point-and-click.

Comment: @jjepsuomi, usually you make your application frame-based (like 95% of the time). But in some cases dialog-based approach is sufficient.

Comment: Hi@Igor so revised shortly put: There is actually no big difference between the two, except dialog based application is usually a "simpler" application than a usual frame application? Could it be interpreted like this? :)

Comment: @jjepsuomi, yes, to some extent. See also catalin's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are different types of top level windows, relevant if you follow general UI rules, not necessarily wxWidgets-related. There are plenty of answers out there, which google can find easily; try a few:

[wxFAQ: What's the difference between a wxFrame and a wxDialog?](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxFAQ#What.27s_the_difference_between_a_wxFrame_and_a_wxDialog.3F)

[wxForum: wxFrame vs wxDialog](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=26719#p114121)

[wxForum: whats is the difference betweem wxDialog and wxFrame?](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=1274)

It has nothing to do with any "resource editor", the way you'll build the UI using a dialog or a frame or anything like that.

Comment: Thank you for your help! =)